# In HTML/Javascript, Can I get an element by coordinates, regardless of the mouse position?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible? Get an element by coordinates, without using mouse or other device/resource, just passing top and left parameter like `getElementByCoordinates(top,left);` ?

Tks,

Manoel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [`document.elementFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM%3adocument.elementFromPoint).

Answer (score 1):

this link:

http://www.roseindia.net/javascript/javascript-elementfrompoint-meth.shtml

should help.

"JavaScript method elementFromPoint returns the presented element at the specified coordinate position given in the arguments."

Answer (score 0):

this is what you are looking for : http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: No, it isn't.  He's looking for the opposite.